# unable to edit a hasMany association child record in ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a Post which has many comments. The problem is that I am able to fetch all the comments but I am  **unable to fetch a single comment** and as a result cannot  edit a single comment. Since I can't fetch a single comment, It means I can't add a single record to the transaction or edit a single record.

The comments is sideloaded and will not be backed by a route and I don't want a **route for any of the comment related controllers**. So I am setting the model for the CommentController in the ApplicationRoute using **controllerFor** and then use the [needs] api to include the model in other comment related controller that may want the model's content.

You can reach the comments by clicking **post** -> then click **post title**  -> 
click *add comment** then save and reclick **editcomment**.

This is the **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GSKAU/)** but the **relevant bit of the code related to this question** is below:

```
 EmBlog.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   setupController: function() {

    this.controllerFor('comment').set('model', EmBlog.Comment.find());      
   }
 });
```

**The Comment Controller**

```
  //Even when I use ArrayController, the error is still there
   EmBlog.CommentController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
      content: null
   });
```

**The controller that handles editing, all the errors happen in the editComment method**

```
 EmBlog.CommentEditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

   needs: ['comment'],
   isEditing: false,

   editComment: function(post) {

     var comment =  this.get('controllers.comment.content');  

     var yk = comment.get('post');

     //this line is undefined 
     console.log(yk);

    var commentEdit = this.set('content', comment);
     console.log(commentEdit);

    transaction = this.get('store').transaction();

    //Uncaught Error: assertion failed: You must pass a record into transaction.add() 
    transaction.add(commentEdit);

    this.transaction = transaction;

    this.set('isEditing', true);

   }

  });
```

**Handlebars for post/show**

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="posts/show">
    {{render 'comment/edit' comment}}
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now everything is **[working and here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GSKAU/1/)** and I am able to edit the comments in the fixtures.

**But the only existing problem is that I am only able to edit the first comment in the fixture. I can't edit the 2nd comment or an new comment unable to edit any new comment that I add**.

I basically fetched the post in postShow through the needs api, then I got the id of the post and passed it as a find argument to  ** EmBlog.Comment.find**. Then I set the content of **EmBlog.CommentEditController** to the result of that find we just did. After this I added the new content of **EmBlog.CommentEditController** to the transaction with  **transaction.add(this.get('content'))**

```
EmBlog.CommentEditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

   needs: ['comment', 'postsShow'],
   isEditing: false,

   editComment: function() {  
     var post = this.get('controllers.postsShow.content');
     console.log(post);

     var postId = post.get('id');
     console.log(postId);

     comment = EmBlog.Comment.find(postId);
     console.log(comment);

     transaction = this.get('store').transaction();

     var updatedContent = this.set('content', comment);
     console.log(updatedContent);
     console.log(this.get('content')); 

    transaction.add(this.get('content'));
    console.log(transaction);

    this.transaction = transaction;   

    this.set('isEditing', true);

   },

  save: function(){

   var comment = this.get('content');
   comment.one('didUpdate', this, function() {
      this.set('isEditing', false);
   });

  this.transaction.commit();
  this.transaction = null;
   console.log(this.get('content')); 
  }  

});
```